# Embedding SVG in HTML

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to understand something very basic about using SVGs in HTML:

I know all about the different methods: as `<img>`, as inline, and as `<object>`. But regarding the **latter**, I just can't figure how SVG properties are then controlled.

I'd like to change the fill colour, for instance. I can do it by editing the `.svg` file itself. But can I also do it from my CSS stylesheet? I'm assuming that adding `<style>` tags in the `.svg` file is probably not the recommended solution.

Comment: reference the stylesheet from the .svg file and it will work fine with <object> embedding

Answer (score 0):

Use `fill` instead `background-color` to style background color
and `stroke` instead `border`
Learn here:https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp
**For example**

```css
svg circle{
fill:red;
stroke:pink;
}
svg path{
fill:red;
}
```

```html
<p>Shape</p>
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4"/>
</svg>

<p>with Path:</p>
<svg height="210" width="400">
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```